# Access Custom Session in ServiceStack from TryAuthenticate

Tags: servicestack

Is there anyway to access a custom session from inside TryAuthenticate on my custom CredentialsAuthProvider?  I need to access a third piece of data to authenticate a user (besides userName and password)

I guess I just need to get that missing piece of data, so any other reasonable technique would be ok.

Comment: I guess I could just dump the value in one of the predefined session properties, but that isn't what I am hoping to do.

Answer (score 1):

To access the session inside `TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)`. You just do something like:  `var session = authService.GetSession();`

Comment: sure, but i needed my custom session object - with this technique I could only access the base